# Why delete defaced posts rather than roll them back?

Tags: discussion

As you can see in the history to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407631/read-before-deleted-by-mods (originally called `"sed" command is removing the spaces inbetween the string rather than just from both sides`) was not the most brilliant question on the site, and obviously it could not be left in its defaced state.

But (automatically?) deleting defaced posts provides way too much power to the defacer, and leaves legitimate questioners vulnerable to attack.

Why wasn't it rolled back instead?

Comment: this was auto-deleted. spam-flagged posts should be auto-rolled-back if they have an unflagged revision.

Comment: That's the python troll. Nuke it and move on.

Comment: @JanDvorak: ah, interesting. I hope I didn't interfere in that process by doing the rollback.

Comment: @Mysticial: I know that's the python troll. But it used to be a different question. Where does that leave the original questioner?

Comment: @rici - Probably not, and your action certainly wasn't incorrect. However, in this case, I believe that the original asker _was_ PyTroll (can't verify, under 10k). Basically, the original question gets asked, then edited to have the defaced text.

Comment: Related question:  I wonder how hard it would be to add random samplings of his rants to the low-quality question filter in order to prevent his "questions" from even being asked or edited in in the first place.

Comment: Looks like the troll was trying to ask a mediocre question and then edit his normal crap in.  No need to keep the original around.  It was deleted when the entire account was nuked (as per usual).

Comment: @Servy: ok, if the OP was him, no problem.

Comment: I can't help but wonder: how did this get approved by three different people?

Comment: @JanDvorak How did what get approved?  There was no suggested edit.  He was editing *his own post*.

Comment: @Servy ah, right. Nuke, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post was defaced by the person that asked it.  The original question, while not nearly as bad as what it was edited to, wasn't asked in good faith.  The original question was merely asked to draw in some views so that the defaced post would get more attention, and possibly last a bit longer before being nuked.  There was no valuable content lost here.

This particular malicious user is a bit of an exception to a lot of normal rules.  In most cases, were a good question to be vandalized in an edit (even by the OP) it would generally be best to roll it back and try to keep the original question, you are correct.